# Check whether element is present

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Is there anyway to check whether an element is present in Selenium web driver? I try to use this code:

```
if @driver.find_element(:link, "Save").displayed? == true
```

but it will break in exception, which is not what I expected because I still want the script to continue running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@driver.find_element` throws an exception called `NoSuchElementError`.

So you can write your own method which uses try catch block and return true when there is no exception and false when there is an exception.

Comment: Is the exception name NoSuchElementException or NoSuchElementError? My Rubymine installation 2018.2 did not find NoSuchElementException.

Comment: It seems like the Exception name is changed. As per the latest doc here : https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Find . Its NoSuchElementError. Thanks @nAQ

Answer (score 12):

I'm not Ruby expert and can make some syntax errors but you can get general idea:

```
if @driver.find_elements(:link, "Save").size() > 0
```

This code doesn't throw `NoSuchElementException`

But this method will "hang" for a while if you have `implicitlyWait` more than zero and there is no elements on the page. 
The second issue - if element exists on the page but not displayed you'll get `true`.

To workaround try to create method:

```
def is_element_present(how, what)
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 0
    result = @driver.find_elements(how, what).size() > 0
    if result
        result = @driver.find_element(how, what).displayed?
    end
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    return result
end
```

Comment: Why is the implicit_wait required? Is it not better not to have it as it will make sure element is present after letting the entire page load? Or am I going wrong in understanding this? Help me!

Answer (score 3):

If it's expected that the element should be on the page no matter what:  use a [selenium wait object](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Wait) with `element.displayed?`, rather than using `begin/rescue`:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
element = $driver.find_element(id: 'foo')
wait.until { element.displayed? } ## Or `.enabled?` etc.
```

This is useful in instances where parts of the page take longer to properly render than others.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `selenium-webdriver version 3.14.0` released earlier this month. I was trying to put a check on `@web_driver_instance.find_element(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), 'text_under_search')]").displayed?` using:

```
element_exists = @wait.until { @web_driver_instance.find_element(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), 'text_under_search')]").displayed? }

 unless element_exists
   #do something if the element does not exist
 end
```

Above failed with `NoSuchElementError` exception so i tried using below:

```
begin
   @wait.until { @web_driver_instance.find_element(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), 'text_under_search')]").displayed? }

rescue NoSuchElementError
  #do something if the element does not exist
end
```

This also did not work for me and failed again with `NoSuchElementError` exception.

Since text presence i was checking was likely to be unique on the page, tried below and **this worked** for me:

```
unless /text_under_search_without_quotes/.match?(@web_driver_instance.page_source)
   #do something if the text does not exist
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Find Element

### Solution #1

```
expect(is_visible?(page.your_element)).to be(false) 
[or]
expect(is_visible?(@driver.find_element(:css => 'locator_value'))).to be(false)
[or]
expect(is_visible?(@driver.first(:css => 'locator_value'))).to be(true)
```

=> **Generic ruby method**

```
  def is_visible?(element)
    begin
      element.displayed?
      return true
    rescue => e
      p e.message
      return false
    end
  end
```

### Solution #2

```
expect(is_visible?(".locator_value")).to be(false)  # default css locator
[or]
expect(is_visible?("locator_value", 'xpath')).to be(true)
[or]
expect(is_visible?("locator_value", 'css')).to be(false)
[or]
expect(is_visible?("locator_value", 'id')).to be(false)
```

=> **Generic ruby method**

```
  def is_visible?(value, locator = 'css')
    begin
      @driver.first(eval(":#{locator}") => value).displayed?
      return true
    rescue => e
      p e.message
      return false
    end
  end
```

---

> Find Elements (list of elements)

### Solution #1

=> **Variable declared in the page class**

```
proceed_until(@driver.find_elements(:css => 'locator_value').size == 0)
[or]
proceed_until(@driver.all(:css => 'locator_value').size == 0)
```

=> **Generic ruby method**

```
  def proceed_until(action)
    init = 0
    until action
      sleep 1
      init += 1
      raise ArgumentError.new("Assertion not matching") if init == 9
    end
  end
```